# I want to use Ubuntu desktop edition for free in my organization. Do I have to pay for that?

Tags: free

I want to install Ubuntu desktop OS on all my laptops at work, So I don't want to invest for support and for OS as well. I heard that Linux is the free solution for operating system requirement generally, but I am seeing it converting in to a paid solution these days.

For using server OS or cloud we may have to pay. But isn't there any such thing which is completely free?

Comment: Welcome to ubuntu :) it is great free and you can install all kind of software that you may need for free

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is completely free, though Canonical sells optional management software, which is how they make their money. (http://www.ubuntu.com/management)